# How to retrieve static data in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

A few of my model have property with a list of state :

thing.js

```
...
status: DS.attr('number'),
statesValues: {1 : "First",2: "Some Choice", 3: "Nothing"}
...
```

How can I in another ember object, access the values from the Thing model ?
I tried to Import the model but I do not even know the correct path to import.

Comment: It seems to me that if you’re attaching static data to models like that, maybe you could extract it to a `util` and import it in all places it’s needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I added this in my model :

```js
export const statusValues ={...}
```

And to use it i import it as needed :

```js
import {statusValues} from 'app-name/models/model-name'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/) will be good solution to share the static data across an Ember.js application and inject it whenever you need.

```
// app/services/static-data.js

import Service from '@ember/service';
import { computed } from '@ember/object'

export default Service.extend({
  statesValues: computed(function() {
    return { 1: 'First', 2: 'Second', 3: 'Third' };
  })
});
```

then you can inject it in any places of you application, components, models, controllers, etc...

```
// app/models/thing.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  staticData: service()

  ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the model from the store using one of the methods written about here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/finding-records/.

*For an existing record*

```
const myModel = await this.store.findRecord('thing', 1);
console.log(myModel.get('statesValues'));
```

*For new record*

```
const myModel = this.store.createRecord('thing', { /* optional defaults go here, e.g., `status: 2,` */ });
console.log(myModel.get('statesValues'));
```

Comment: And when the app has no record yet ? How do you display the values in the first form ?

Comment: @Syl I've updated the answer to show how to work with a new record.